Try to change color of a stacked bar chart in Python
I have created a stacked bar chart from a pandas DataFrame object.
My DataFrame df looks like this when printed to output:
Grade        4a  4b  4c  5a  5a+  5b  5b+  5c  5c+  6a  6a+  6b  6b+  6c
Month                                                                   
Apr 2024  0   0   0   0   1    2   1    2   7    3  16   12   3    2   0
Aug 2024  0   0   0   0   1    0   2    0   4    5   8    3   1    0   0
Jun 2024  0   0   0   0   0    0   0    0   0    1   4    2   0    1   0
Mar 2024  0   1   0   0   1    0   0    2   3    0   4    0   0    0   0
May 2024  0   0   1   1   1    1   4    1  12    3  20    8   5    1   0

I've then used the following code to create a bar 100% stacked bar chart.
df_norm = df.div(df.sum(axis=1), axis = 0)
df_norm.plot(kind="bar", stacked=True, title='Climbing Grades Monthly Progress')
plt.bar(df_norm.columns[1], df_norm.values, "red")
plt.show()

And I get the expected (unformatted) output:

And now I want to format the colors, each grade should be a unique color.  I figured I have to work with the bar object, something like:
bars = ax.bar(x, y, color='grey')    

But this gives me no way of accessing individual legend items.  How to I access them?

Each grade is already "a unique color". What is your goal? Do you just want a better color scheme or do you need to choose specific colors?

You can use a colormap to format the colors, as mentioned here in the documentation of pandas.DataFrame.plot, in colormap.
I've modified your code as follows and it seems to work.
df_norm.plot(kind='bar', stacked=True, title='Climbing Grades Monthly Progress', colormap='jet')

Screenshot of output.
You can also refer to this link for built-in colormaps in matplotlib, or create your own if you want to further customize the colors.

Actually you don't need to create a colormap if you want to customize each color for each category. Just specify "colors=[color1, color2, ...,]" inside the plot() function in a way similar to the post mentioned in @Joooeey 's comment would work. For example, color=[(a,a,a) for a in np.linspace(0,1,15)].
